# How to get the result from Task.Factory.StartNew<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Please let me know if I can run more than one `Task.Factory.StartNew` statement in parallel.

Some thing like this

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(mirrorId, null,"DEV"));
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(mirrorId, null, "PROD"));
```

If so. how to get the output of the statement and use it.

I have used the statement like below before. where the application will wait till I get the output from the thread.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(mirrorId, null,"DEV"));
return (List<AccessDetails>)task.ContinueWith(tsk => accdet = task.Result.ToList()).Result;
```

Comment: Not sure if i get your question right but if you want to wait till execution finished you can just use Task.Wait() and then grab the Task.Result.

Comment: @Mecaveli [Task.Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) blocks until complete, there is no need to call Task.Wait() first if you are dealing with a single task.

Comment: Thx for the correction. He´s dealing with multible tasks - was meant to be Task.WaitAll.

Answer (score 13):

You can let multiple tasks run, and wait for all of them to be finished like this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(mirrorId, null,"DEV"));        
var task1 =  Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(mirrorId, null, "PROD"));  

var allTasks = new Task[]{task, task1};

Task.WaitAll(allTasks);

var result = task.Result;
var result1 = task1.Result;
```

If you want to just wait for the first one to finish, you can use `Task.WaitAny` for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily run more than one task

you can use Task Result [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613.aspx)

you can create an object which can hold you resullts pass it to the task and update it
should look something like this

```
MyResultObeject res = new MyResultObject 
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<AccessDetails>>(() => this.GetAccessListOfMirror(res,mirrorId, null,"DEV"));
```

just dont forget to check whether the task has finished